# Is gradual progressive training better than greasing the groove for longer distances?

Tags: running, 5k

I am currently training for the 5-kilometer run. It's what I specialize in. The track I'm running along is a 1k loop with a lot of ups and downs. My current time is an average of 5:15 per loop (I haven't run in a while).

I'm trying to get it as close to three minutes as possible. Fact is, I can do 1 loop in 3 minutes, but I'd fade away by my second loop around the track. And herein lies the question, for training would you recommend that I start at 3 minutes for my first loop and try to get as close to three minutes for my second and then my third, and so on and so forth; or should I do a gentle 5 minutes for all loops and reduce each lap by approximately 10 seconds every week simultaneously until I'm as close to three minutes as I can get? (PS: I have quite a bit of time to train)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [training pace vs. race pace](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32203/what-is-a-good-training-pace-vs-a-recent-race-pace/32222#32222)

Answer (score 1):

Easy running will give you cardio and hard running will give you speed. If you are just starting out perhaps running 5x 5 minutes are better at this point.

After building up your cardio do both. Run easy the day after running hard. Alternatively run an easy five then a hard five for a good 10k. Besides running easy on sore legs is hard.

Variety is very important in a running plan, so sticking to one workout is not good. Think in terms of weeks and months including hard weeks and easy weeks. Never run hard too much and always ensure your rested and recovered before running hard again. Thats the key.